# How to prevent the bloc from being closed when moving to the next route using pushReplacement

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have two screens, the first we will call FistScreen, on this screen you will find the BlocProvider.create and the second screen the SecondScreen, in this one I am passing the bloc via BlocProvider.value, but I use pushReplacement, but when discarding the route that has the create block is closed. How can I prevent the bloc from being closed when passing via value but without using global instantiation. Is there any way? Searching on SO I found a similar problem, but without a solution. Any help is welcome.

```
import 'package:flutter/Material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const FirstScreen());
  }
}
```

> FirstScreen

```
import 'package:flutter/Material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(create: (_) => BlocA(), child: const FirstScreenMain());
  }
}

class FirstScreenMain extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreenMain({super.key});

  @override
  State<FirstScreenMain> createState() => _FirstScreenMainState();
}

class _FirstScreenMainState extends State<FirstScreenMain> {
  late BlocA _blocA;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _blocA = BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('first screen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return BlocProvider.value(
                        value: _blocA,
                        child: const SecondeScreen(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Push and replacement to Second')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> SecondScreen

```
import 'package:flutter/Material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  late BlocA _blocA;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _blocA = BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```